# Can a static variable be declared extern in C?

Tags: c

So, let's say, I have:

`file1.c`

```
int i;
static int j;
int main ()
{
    for ( int k = 0; k < 10; k++ )
    {
       int foo = k;
    }
}
```

`file2.c`

```
{
// the following statements are before main.
extern int i; // this is acceptable, I know since i acts as a global variable in the other file
extern int j; // Will this be valid? 
extern int foo; // Will this be valid as well?
}
```

I therefore, have a doubt that the statements marked with a question mark, will they be valid?

Comment: This can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841762/why-wont-extern-link-to-a-static-variable

Comment: What prevented you from asking your compiler?

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense, extern and static are each other's opposites. You are essentially asking "can a red car be blue while it stays red?".

Comment: @molbdnilo compilers are not authoritative

Answer (score 14):

No! `static` globals have file scope (internal linkage), so you can't use them as they have external linkage... This does not means that you cannot have a variable of the same name with external linkage but it cannot be that one that is `static`.

Correct for `i`.

Incorrect for `j`, at least it cannot be the one defined in `file1.c`.

Incorrect for `foo`, at least for the local variable used in `file2.c` which does not have external linkage (no linkage at all). A local variable only exists when the block where it is declared is activated, so having access to it outside is a non-sense.

Answer (score 0):

**extern int j;**    is not a valid -> static variables are with in the file scope

**extern int foo;**  is not valid -> foo is a local variable whose scope is with in the 'for' loop