# When is `extern` unavoidable for variables in C?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, extern

> Answers to [the question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841762/why-wont-extern-link-to-a-static-variable) don't answer my question. I know what `extern` *does.* The question is if we *ever* ***need*** `extern`. It only seems *cleaner* to use `extern` (and compile with `-fno-common`), but it doesn't seem there are situations when we *need* it.

Similar questions have already been answered (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255535/is-extern-keyword-for-function-necessary-at-all-in-c)), but this question is a bit different.

Say, I have two files:

**file_a.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sixsixsix = 666;

void lucky_seven();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  printf("%d\n", sixsixsix);
  lucky_seven();
  printf("%d\n", sixsixsix);
  return 0;
}
```

**file_b.c:**

```
int sixsixsix;

void lucky_seven(){
  sixsixsix = 777;
}
```

I can compile with GCC using `gcc -std=c99 file_a.c file_b.c` with no errors. The compiled program gives as expected the output:

```
666
777
```

I only get errors if I compile with `-fno-common`. In this case it is necessary to use `extern` in file_b.c:

**file_b.c:**

```
extern int sixsixsix;

void lucky_seven(){
  sixsixsix = 777;
}
```

Aside from this special case, that is, if I have a compiler which ***doesn't*** put multiply declared variables in a common block, is there *any* other use for `extern` for variables? Can you give me example code in which `extern` becomes unavoidable?

Comment: Am I missing something? How do you inform the compiler that you are using a variable defined in another file?

Comment: Well, make it *char* in the other source file and consider if you still like what is going to happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why wont extern link to a static variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841762/why-wont-extern-link-to-a-static-variable)

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841762/why-wont-extern-link-to-a-static-variable/2841771#2841771.

Comment: @HansPassant: ok, in **file_b.c**, we use `char sixsixsix` and (so that we don't get an overflow) we also use `sixsixsix = 7`. Program compiles successfully, but gives output `666 [linebreak] 519`. So `lucky_seven()` only overwrites the last byte! 666 = 0x29A, which becomes 0x207 = 519. ***I do not like this at all!!!*** Why is `-fno-common` not standard? The standard setting seems to be a source of nasty errors!

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2p4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *extern* keywords is necessary when your project consist of multiple files and a variable defined in one of the source file is needed in another one.

For example, if you *define* the variable in source1.c, then you **must** declare it as extern in source2.c (directly or by including an header file).

Any other file that reference the variable **must** declare it as extern.

See this [**post1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c) for a *very very* detailed explanation of the use of the extern keyword

---

### EDIT

I was curious and thus continued to search on this topic.

This is the another relevant [**post2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490693/tentative-definitions-in-c99-and-linking) which is directly addressing your question. And again the answer comes from Jonathan Leaffler.

Here, for sake of completeness, I will report an excerpt of the above question/answer.

The problem raised in the post was specifically: *why if you define a variable in two distinct source files the compiler doesn't even rise a warning?*

**Short answer is** that you do not violate any constrain in the Standard and the compiler is free to decide what to do.

Moreover, as shown in **post1**, it is possible to write a code that actually works, using gcc and clang (and maybe other compilers too).

**But why we should bother?** *We know that is better to use extern!* I found very interesting the observation of the OP in **post2**:

> Note: this is important because the question occurs in the context of
>   static analysis. If the two files may refuse to be linked on some
>   platform, the analyzer should complain, but if every compilation
>   platform accepts it then there is no reason to warn about it.

---

**The relevant paragraph of the C standard is:**

> J.5.11 Multiple external definitions
>
> There may be more than one external definition for the identifier of
>   an object, with or without the explicit use of the keyword extern; if
>   the definitions disagree, or more than one is initialized, the
>   behavior is undefined (6.9.2).

This means that the result is Undefined Behaviour (see also the comment to the post). And, as Jonathan Leffler said:

> One of the things that can happen is that the program behaves as you
>   expect; and J.5.11 says, approximately, "you might be lucky more often
>   than you deserve"

Confirmed in the comment by Johannes Schaub:

> To be really clear whether it's allowed or not: No it's undefined
>   behavior in C. It's like doing a[10] = 0; even if a is a int a[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c);

---

### Conclusion

Defining a variable in multiple files is **Undefined Behaviour**, don't do that unless you are doing some wired test. Use extern!

Comment: (Don't have enough rep to upvote your answer). Ok, so after reading the linked post, especially the "Not so good way to define global variables" part, I would tentatively say that the answer to my question is: "You never *need* `extern`. It is just better to use it." Right?

Comment: I would say you need it, you can avoid it at your own risk!

Comment: Ok, with GCC and CLANG it compiles without using `extern`. It does indeed **not** work with the Tiny C Compiler with standard settings.

Comment: @VIofSwords please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I copied a lot from your posts ;)

Comment: after 6 month: what you quoted under "J.5.11 Multiple external definitions" is what makes the behavior in the example in the question *possible*. It is a compiler extension. *Without* that extension it is undefined behavior. And the relevant portion of the standard for that is 6.9/5 of the ISO/IEC 9899-2011 standard.